# What key is Keys.Context1 tied to in Qt/QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm currently building a proof of concept application, on windows, testing out what I can do with QML but the end result is going to run on an embedded Linux system (which I'll need to learn too). I've been working with key handling (Enter, Up, down, Left and Right etc.) and noticed that there are 4 keys marked as Context1 to 4.

In the [QtQuick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html) docs there is reference to Keys.Context1..4 with associated onPressed events but not about how they are used.

> context1Pressed(KeyEvent event)
>
> This signal is emitted when the Context1 key has been pressed. The event parameter provides information about the event.
>
> The corresponding handler is onContext1Pressed.

How do I find out what physical keys these are bound to, or how can I specify which keys they bind to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key codes for the Keys enumeration is in `CoreLib/Global/QNamespace.h`; the `Key_Context1..4` keys are bound to the key codes `0x01100000..3`. As Tod has mentioned the keys are designed for the mobile platform, similar mobile keys are defined close to the context keys, for example: `Key_Call`, `Key_Camera` etc.

The Qt Embedded framework apparently reads the keys directly from the tty device (on Linux) and so doesn't use the OS key mappings, there is a patch that allows you to specify bindings like `{ Qt::Key_A, Qt::Key_Context1, Qt::Key_Unknown, Qt::Key_Unknown }` from this page: http://llg.cubic.org/patches/qtegerman.html I'm not sure yet if that helps.

I hoped that I'd be able to use the OS inbuilt key mapping features, but if it is reading directly from the input device I'm not sure this is possible.

I'll update this if I learn any more.

### **Update**

The platform we're running on has an API that deals with the keyboard device so Qt doesn't access it directly; I add a listener for each button and then send the key press event to Qt using:

```
QKeyEvent* key = QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Context1, Qt::NoModifier);
qApp->SendEvent(view, key).
```

where `view` is the QML DeclarativeView (or equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

Qt/QML is intended for use on the desktop (Windows, Linux, Mac) and mobile platforms. I **strongly** suspect the contextX key events and handlers are for mobile platform use. I did some googling and you can [see the intent on this Qtopia site](http://www.dashwerks.com/misc.orig/qtopia-free-2.1.0/doc/html/phoneapps.html). So you won't use these keys on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I see though that Qt has retired the QT Extended product, could this mean that the ContextKeys are redundant now? The final product we're building will work in a similar way with a context bar at the bottom of the screen with four corresponding keys. We've got Digia coming to give us some training next week so I'll ask them for their input.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing the answer you get from them.

Comment: I've added an answer with what I found out, but until we get our hardware I won't be able to test it; I'll add more when I can.